# Heroku config vars and gatsby

Tags: heroku, environment-variables, gatsby

Adding environment variables in .env.development and .env.production works as expected (as per https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/). I can access them through `process.env` in my front end code.

I don't want to version control my .env.production, so I'm wondering if there's a way to load Heroku config vars (that are set through `heroku config:set SOME_VAR=1`) in my front end code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I personally like to add env variables in Heroku by using the settings-> Config Vars -> Reveal config vars then setting the KEY VALUE pair.

If you were wanting to access those env variables in JS, here's something from the Gatsby docs

> In addition to .env.* files, any variable in the environment prefixed with GATSBY_ will be made available in browser JavaScript.

Ref: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/

1. I would go into the Heroku settings and add `GATSBY_ASSETS_URL` to my KEY and `http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname` as the VALUE.
2. Then in my code I would have a `.env.development` with the following line `GATSBY_ASSETS_URL=http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev/bucketname`.
3. To use my envronment variable in JS

`` render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={`${process.env.GATSBY_ASSETS_URL}/logo.png`} alt="Logo" />
    </div>
  )
} ``